# Can configuration profile be added to iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, certificate, ios-simulator, xcode7

The company I work for has a lot of apple devices and they are built with a variety of different policies / configuration profile, as I can imagine a lot of companies do.

Im wondering if there is a way of loading the configuration policies on to my iOS simulator. This will allow me to run my automation suite on the simulator and run the test agents different devices + policies.

Im also hoping this will help the community get past some of the annoying SSL issues.

We are currently using Mass360 to build the policies onto our phisical devices.

So can you install configuration policies on to a the iOS simulator and if so whats the best way of doing so?

Comment: To my knowledge no, the main reason is that it is a simulator not an emulator. The iOS simulator is just simulating the iOS UI on top of OS X. Wat you want is to emulate iOS system it self, which is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (at least as of iOS 9.3 Simulator Runtime).

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to add a configuration profile to enable use an HTTPS proxy for debugging. On physical devices I'd open the configuration in Safari, then go to Settings and enable it in "Downloaded Profiles". However there is no such thing on the simulator.

[Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/) suggests a few options which may be useful:

- [Install certificates on a simulator](https://proxyman.io/ios-simulator) (Available in the free version)
- [Add Atlantis to your cocoapods](https://docs.proxyman.io/atlantis/atlantis-for-ios) to automate the process